# voting with Catalyst

Tags: catalyst, voting

I have multiple wallets (two on Daedalus, two on Yoroi and one Nami.) How do I vote with each wallet? Catalyst on my iPhone will only allow me to register one wallet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You either have to vote with your first account, than reinstall the app (or just wipe its storage) and vote again with your second account.

Alternatively you can use any application cloning app on iOS that will allow you to setup the same application with two acocunts.